# How to style the navigator button of p-galleria (primeng) in angular 9?

Tags: css, angular, primeng

How can I change the color of the navigator button of p-galleria on primeng?I have already tried to override the background-color property of `.p-galleria .p-galleria-item-nav` with css but it didn't work.

```
.p-galleria .p-galleria-item-nav {
     background-color: slategray !important;
}
```

Comment: Try to add `:host ::ng-deep` in front of `.p-galleria .p-galleria-item-nav {` to override PrimeNG styles.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the style in the global css file

style.css

```css
.p-galleria .p-galleria-item-nav {
     background-color: slategray !important;
}
```

> this style will effect all project and it is way good to overwrite component base theme